# How to set <s:param> value of <s:url> tag dynamically using javascript in struts2

Tags: java, javascript

I am new to Struts2.I unable to pass  tag value dynamically through javascript.I have done this way

```
<s:url id="temId" action="updateProduct.action" var="productTag"> 
<s:param name="prodId"><s:property value="hdnId"/></s:param>
</s:url>
<s:hidden name="hdnId"/>
```

this hidden field value is populated through javascript function onclick on gridrow
This hidden field is storing value properly.But it is not showing inside of param tag.please give some possible solution

Comment: Will you describe in detail what you trying to do? your question not clear.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Struts2 is server side only whereas JavaScript is client side. Thus you can't create/fill struts tags using JavaScript (unless you execute it on the server side which wouldn't make sense IMHO).

Comment: @saptak: How can I do what? Your question doesn't make sense. The JSP code exists only at server-side. JavaScript only sees the generated HTML. What do you want to change in the HTML?

Comment: Sorry, My problem is how can I set hidden field value as url param value?

Comment: @saptak: URL of what? A link? A form action? Forget about the JSP and look at the generated HTML in the browser. What would you like to change in this HTML code using JavaScript?

Comment: URL of a link code is <a href="<s:property value="#productTag"/>"/>Click Here</a>.

Comment: `<s:property value="#productTag"/>` that's not an url. What does it look like in the generated HTML? You don't have struts tags there, unless your struts is not working at all. - In what way should that be dynamic? Please add more information to your question (not as a comment here as it is harder to format, read and find for others).

Comment: @Thomas: This <s:property value="#productTag"/> generates an url link like "/project_name/updateProduct.action?prodId=some value" and value of property tag "#productTag" ref. from <s:url> .I am facing problem when I want to set <s:param> value using a hidden field value.And this hidden field value is populated when I click a grid row of same page.Onclick function I set hidden field value and I want to pass it as url parameter value.

Comment: Then assign an ID to the link, get the link by ID, and change its URL: document.getElementById("myLink").href = encodeURI("/project_name/updateProduct.action?prodId=" + theProductId);

Comment: @JB Nizet: Thanks a lot.It's working.I have followed your suggestion.